# CABasicAnimation without interpolation values

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

Apple's documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation) states that:

> The fromValue, byValue and toValue properties define the values being interpolated between. All are optional, and no more than two should be non-nil. The object type should match the type of the property being animated.
>
> The interpolation values are used as follows:
>
> - All properties are nil. Interpolates between the previous value of keyPath in the target layer’s presentation layer and the current value of keyPath in the target layer’s presentation layer.

How can I make this work without specifying any of the `fromValue`, `byValue`, or `toValue`?

Here, I'm just animating the change of the `cornerRadius` property.

I know how to make this animation using `toValue`. But I just want to know if there is an even simpler code than this to achieve it:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let rect = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)
let view = UIView(frame: rect)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

let layer = CALayer()
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 75, width: 150, height: 150)
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

layer.cornerRadius = 15
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:#keyPath(CALayer.cornerRadius))
animation.toValue = layer.bounds.width / 2
animation.duration = 1
layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: Can you describe the animation you're trying to create?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some situations, where you have already set the layer's final value without animation, you can skip setting both the `toValue` and the `fromValue` in your CABasicAnimation, because the runtime gets the `fromValue` from the current value of the presentation layer and the `toValue` from the current value of the model layer.

For example, in my own code, it turns out that I can reduce this full form of specifying an animation...

```
        let startValue = arrow.transform
        let endValue = CATransform3DRotate(startValue, .pi/4.0, 0, 0, 1)
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        arrow.transform = endValue
        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:#keyPath(CALayer.transform))
        anim.duration = 0.8
        let clunk = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints:0.9, 0.1, 0.7, 0.9)
        anim.timingFunction = clunk
        anim.fromValue = startValue
        anim.toValue = endValue
        arrow.add(anim, forKey:nil)
```

...to this (notice that `fromValue` and `toValue` are omitted):

```
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        arrow.transform = CATransform3DRotate(arrow.transform, .pi/4.0, 0, 0, 1)
        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:#keyPath(CALayer.transform))
        anim.duration = 0.8
        let clunk = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints:0.9, 0.1, 0.7, 0.9)
        anim.timingFunction = clunk
        arrow.add(anim, forKey:nil)
```

However, I do not recommend that approach. It is much more reliable always to supply both the `fromValue` and the `toValue`. Yes, it's two more lines of code, but that is a small price to pay for avoiding confusion. Sometimes, clarity *is* simplicity.

Comment: See the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_using_a_cabasicanimation This shows the fullest form of using CABasicAnimation along with some reduced forms and an explanation of why you can reduce.

Comment: The problem is exactly the "assure" in your comment on the other answer. You cannot be "sure", so it's better just to give the values.

Comment: Added an actual example where I was able to omit both `toValue` and `fromValue`. But don't. It won't always work and you'll just confuse yourself.

Comment: Great explanation, and great books (I own Programming iOS 7 and 11), highly recommended!

Comment: Thanks for asking about something I actually know something about! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I got your point and I agree, but just for the sake of the argument, the code from the second snippet doesn't produce an animation for me in playground, but the code from the first snippet does. I guess there's something more to do here.

Comment: Well, playgrounds are not the real world. I assure you my downloadable example does work as advertised when you download the actual project and run it as a project.